# Term for wanting something but not wanting to give something else up to have it

Tags: single-word-requests

I have been trying to think of the word to describe wanting to have something while not being prepared to give up something else to have it.

My example is, *"a person wants to live closer to nature but they are unwilling to sacrifice the modern conveniences of urban living to achieve that."*

These are contradictory ideas, but I cannot think of the word to express them. It is an attitude, and I just cannot think of the term.
The word 'selfish' definitely doesn't fit in the context. Is it a paradox?

Answer (score 1):

**velleity** is one possibility.
From M-W: (noun) 1. [the lowest degree of volition; a slight wish or tendency](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/velleity)

Definitions listed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velleity) include "a desire to see something done, but not enough desire to make it happen"

However, this is not what you want if you want something very badly, just less than you want something else.